# How to query table and output average,sum,position,

Tags: php, mysql

Much great guys,any help please am new in php and mysql I have a table 'student' with the following fields and passmarks.

```
id idnumber | Math | English | Geography | Ict | Biology
1  va01       100    80        89          100   82
2  va02       90     79        70          30    76
3  va03       100    100       100         100   90
```

Some thing make me stacking is how to query by php and output the (Average,Total,Position,out of) from msql, and result suppose to be arranged according to high passmark.
Example: first student is va03, second one is va01, third one is va02, suppose to be like this

```
1: va03  math English Geograph Ict Biology  Average Total  out of
         100  100     100      100 90       98      490    3

2: va01  Math English Geograph Ict Biology  Average Total  out of
         90   79      70       80  76       79      395    3

3: va02  Math English Geograph Ict Biology  Average Total  out of
         90   79      70       30  76       69        345  3
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here's an introduction to PDO in PHP, which will help you accomplish what you want: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: 1. Normalize your data. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much help on teh PHP but the SQL for this should be fairly simple..

```
Select idnumber, math, english, geography, ict, biology,
Average(math + english + geography + ict + biology)/5  as `mAverage`, 
(Select count(*) from student) as `out of `,
math + english + geography + ict + biology as `Total`
From student
Group by idnumber, math, english, geography, ict, biology
order by Average desc;
```

Comment: Thank you but this cant help me since am using php and mysql

Comment: if you run the above in mySQL you should get the results desired.  HOwever, displaying it though PHP is where my answer fails  SQL isn't microsoft SQL it's just the syntax for Structured Query Language and isn't limited to one database engine. The above should work in MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc (though the `) is limited to mySQL I belive.

Comment: Ok, where should I put those query, am using Adobe dreamweaver!!

Comment: MySQL database has a query screen within the UI that would show you that the query above results achieve the desired output.  PHP would be used to connect to the database, pass in the above query, obtain a record set object that you would then use to display the results.  I've 0 knowledge of dreamweaver and nearly zero knowledge of PHP.  I do know how to write a query.  Again not much help on the display side. which is where PHP and dreamweaver come in I think.

Comment: MySQL workbench 6.0 shows you how to use the SQL editor.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor.html.  Aside from it's use, PHP, dreamweaver I'm no help

Comment: I tried this but gives an error sayes,  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'idnumber + math + english + geography + ict + biology as `Total` From stdreg_ex' at line 4

Comment: Shouldn't have had IDnumber in the average and should have called average something other than a reserved word. and was mssing a comma after out of